# Getting application error after serving Django on Herohu, 'module' object has no attribute Cling

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn, django-settings, django-wsgi

- I have Been using this guide [Getting Started with Django on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django)

### requirements.txt

```
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==1.7.7
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
djrill==1.3.0
gunicorn==19.3.0
Pillow==2.7.0
psycopg2==2.6
requests==2.6.0
static3==0.5.1
```

---

### Procfile

```
web: gunicorn MY_DJANGO_APP.wsgi --log-file -
```

### wsgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MY_DJANGO_APP.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

---

### Heroku log

```
State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn MY_Django_App.wsgi --log-file -`
app[web.1]: [2015-03-29 07:17:55 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
app[web.1]: [2015-03-29 07:17:56 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
app[web.1]: [2015-03-29 07:17:55 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:17329 (3)
app[web.1]: [2015-03-29 07:17:55 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
app[web.1]: [2015-03-29 07:17:55 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
app[web.1]: [2015-03-29 07:17:56 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/MY_Django_App/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 48, in __init__
app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cling'
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 48, in __init__
app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
app[web.1]:     application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cling'
app[web.1]:     application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
app[web.1]:     self.cling = static.Cling(base_dir)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
app[web.1]: [2015-03-29 07:17:56 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
app[web.1]:   File "/app/MY_Django_App/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
app[web.1]:     self.cling = static.Cling(base_dir)
app[web.1]: [2015-03-29 07:17:56 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 48, in __init__
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
app[web.1]:   File "/app/MY_Django_App/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
app[web.1]:     self.cling = static.Cling(base_dir)
app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cling'
app[web.1]: [2015-03-29 07:17:56 +0000] [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
app[web.1]: [2015-03-29 07:17:56 +0000] [3] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
app[web.1]:     self.cling = static.Cling(base_dir)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
app[web.1]:   File "/app/MY_Django_App/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cling'
app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 48, in __init__
app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
app[web.1]:     application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
app[web.1]:     application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app[web.1]: [2015-03-29 07:17:56 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/feed" host=MY_Django_App.herokuapp.com request_id=e6de6503-58ea-4a05-b8fc-20321ace144a fwd="91.133.185.43" dyno=web.1 connect=5000ms service= status=503 bytes=
```

---

### The more eye catching error

```
app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
app[web.1]:     application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cling'
app[web.1]:     application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

---

What should I do with the Cling thing error? Is there anything I have missed while the project setup?

Comment: first of all, the output form the log file seems shuffled. This line seems to be the place where the error is being raised `self.cling = static.Cling(base_dir)`. I don't have knowledge of gunicorn or heroku, but from what I see, the error should most likely be caused by some incorrect python package version, or by some python package missing.

Comment: Thanks for you comment but I'm using the same version mentioned in the tutorial: dj-static==0.0.6

Answer (score 0):

The error itself means that something is calling a method or getting an attribute on a python module instead of the class within the module.

This could happen if your module filename is the same as the class inside. Ie if you had cling.py and inside was a python class called cling.

Im not really up on python3 and I'm not sure whats causing this, I'm tempted to say it might be a circular dependency issue, or maybe one of the dependencies of dj-static ie static has been updated and caused this issue?

Maybe try to specify only dj-static in your requirements and remove the dependency on static as I believe dj-static should resolve its dependency on static by itself and that may be causing a conflict.

The documentation on heroku could be out of date.

Comment: I think dj-static is not stable and maintained well. DjangoWhiteNoise did the great job. Thanks for follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I started using DjangoWhiteNoise instead of dj-static and no more problems.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an extraneous `__init__.pyc` in a subdirectory, where it shouldn't be. (Reason: as I moved modules around, the `__init__.py` was correctly deleted, but the compiled `__init__.pyc` had been left behind.)
Django's autodiscover then threw this error.
Deleting the unwanted `__init__.pyc` file fixed it.